# Jackson Deserialization Issue

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have the following JSON I am receiving from a REST call:

```
"socialConnectionsData" : {
  "friends" : [ {
    "friend" : {
      "firstname" : "John",
      "lastname" : "Doe"
     }
    }]
}
```

My current class looks like this:

```
public class SocialConnectionsData {
private List<Friend> friends;

public List<Friend> getFriends() {
    return friends;
}

public void setFriends(List<Friend> friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}    
}
```

However, I get an Jackson exception stating that "friend" is an unrecognized field.  How would I have a collection of Friends and maintain the type of Friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you have an extra property name in there.  Jackson is expecting JSON like this to correspond to your Objects:

```
"socialConnectionsData" : {
  "friends" : [ {
      "firstname" : "John",
      "lastname" : "Doe"
    }]
}
```

You shouldn't need to do anything to maintain the type of Friend because your list is declared with that as a generic parameter.

If you want to go the other way around and make your objects match the JSON, then you'll need an extra level of indirection like so:

```
public class SocialConnectionsData {
    private List<FriendWrapper> friends;

    public List<FriendWrapper> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(List<FriendWrapper> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }    
}

public class FriendWrapper {
    private Friend friend;

    public Friend getFriend() {
        return friend;
    }

    public void setFriend(Friend friend) {
        this.friend = friend;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, I am not trying to get JSON to match my object structure but the other way around.  I am attempting to create an object structure to match the JSON being returned since I cannot alter the JSON response. In this case the JSON is being generated by XStream.

Comment: All righty...I updated my answer to show how to go either way...either update the classes to match the JSON or update the JSON to match the classes.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Because the property is "friends" not "friend"?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON must match your Object structure, and here error message does point out the problem: your main level object (SocialConnectionsData) does not have property "socialConnectionsData". Name of the class is irrelevant.

So either you should drop outermost "socialConnectionsData" or use wrapper object like:

```
class Wrapper {
  public SocialConnectionsData socialConnectionsData; // and/or setter to set it
}
```

and bind to it. This would make JSON and object structure match.